# How to run code periodically in the background in Tizen 5.5?

Tags: c#, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I need to run a code every x minutes and show a notification if needed.

How can I run a code in the background periodically while the app is closed?

---

So far what I've reached to is that I lock the CPU and call a timer to run periodically. The problem with this is that it drains the battery and the watch shows a notification suggesting to close the app.

```
public static void LockCpu()
{
    Power.RequestLock(PowerLock.Cpu, 0);
}

public static void ReleaseCpu()
{
    Power.ReleaseLock(PowerLock.Cpu);
}
```

It's for Tizen .NET for wearable watches.

Thanks.

Comment: `it drains the battery and the watch shows a notification suggesting to close the app.` = what I hoped would happen. :) - you should look at push notifications instead https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/messaging/push-notification

Comment: @RandRandom Yes it's a good thing, no complain about that :)

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks for suggesting push notifications. In my case I need to run a code in the background first (check some client data like GPS) and show a notification if it was needed. Sending a notification from a server won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Alarm API to run code periodically.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/guides/alarm/alarms/
https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/api/TizenFX/API7/api/Tizen.Applications.AlarmManager.html

To prevent battery drain, that is not guaranteed to be accurate.